# module not found error in Access 2007

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have a database and I was working on it this morning. I created a filter form for a table which just takes parameters and when you click submit on this form, it checks for those fields in the where clause of the report. Anyway, I did this in Access 2013 and it worked fine. My colleague tried to run it in Access 2007 and it gives an error saying "Module not found" and takes me to the VB code in debug mode. I thought something went wrong with the database and I checked it on my computer and it is working fine. It just doesn't run on his computer. What can be the problem? and how can I solve it?

Comment: If it takes you to debug mode then what code-line does it highlight?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Access 2013, but I assume that you need to enable the content, as we do in 2010. When the file is opened a notification bar appears below the Ribbon (in 2010) to enable content.

*Edited* I got this the wrong way round (problem is not opening from 2013, but from 2007) but opening in 2007 you would still need to enable the content.

**Added**
Almost sounds as if the form's `Has Module` property has been set to No, but this seems unlikely. I don't like to open databases in different Access versions - I don't trust Access to do this successfully (I've had many problems with this). I would start a blank database in Access 2007 and import all of the database objects, then Compact and Repair.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. It is related to some form that it says is missing. But in 2013, it works perfectly